# How to get source file rowcount in data flow task SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, rowcount

I have a data flow task which contain excel file as the source and script component as the destination.

Is there a way to get the number of rows in my excel file and pass it my script component?

I already tried with Row count component but its value gets updated only after the data flow task is done.

Comment: I had posted an answer for a similar question looking for row counts of a file. You should be able to use the same code to get what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127648/ssis-matching-csv-file-to-control-file-before-loading-to-destination/39136146#39136146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use `Row Count` component you have to create two dataflow tasks:

- the first only contains `Excel Source` + `Row Count component`
- the second contains `Excel Source` + `Derived Column` + `Destination`

*The derived column is used to add the variable that store the row count as a new column*

*More info in this question [Does variable value set by Row Count Transformation take effect during execution of DFT in SSIS? or Conditional Split can read a variable correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384108/does-variable-value-set-by-row-count-transformation-take-effect-during-execution)*

Comment: This what I actually did but I just stored the result of Row Count Component into a variable with scope package and just access it in my script component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script task before the dataflow that counts the rows in the Excel file and stores it in a variable.